# Javascript: How to speed up setTimeout function on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website that asks me to complete a task, then once I complete that task it asks me to wait 1 hour before completing the next task.
What I am looking for here is to speed up the timer on this website instead of waiting for 1 hour.

**How it works:**
On Website I simply have to click on 'Roll' button then a timer start in descending order like (1:00)...(45:00)...(00:05) so on till it reach (00:00). Once it reach (00:00) it replace this timer to Roll button.
This timer only display Minutes and Second column.
It does not take computer time.

**Changes I need:**
Since it run in descending order or backward in seconds, I want to speedup this process so that instead of waiting for 1 hour I just have to wait for 20 or 30 minutes.

**What I can't do:**
Since this is a third party website so I cannot make changes in the website code I can only use browser console to run javascript code so I can override existing code on it.

**Here is the Javascript for this timer:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#time_remaining').countdown({
            until: +3600,
            format: 'MS'
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds();
    }, 3600 * 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: That sounds like you could just call `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds` directly. However, that won't do anything if they're also validating the time on the server.

Comment: log `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds` to the console, it should print out the text of the function (hopefully it's not minified and is understandable). If all it does is just refresh the page, then what you're trying to do might be pointless.

Comment: Yes, it seems that time is valided from server.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds` is global. So, you may try to override it like

```
var myTimeout = 3600; // 1 min

RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds = function(speedUp) {
   if(!speedUp) { // just to cancel "legal" call
     return;
   }
   RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds();
}

setTimeout(function(){ RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds(true); }, myTimeout);
```

Comment: No, per OP request this would be called only once, from the console.

Comment: I'd modify this answer to first save whatever's originally inside `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds` as a new variable and then call that inside of the new function. That wouldn't fix the pointlessness of what OP is trying to do though.

Comment: And how does that help him? Unnecessary loss of one minute because the function will not do anything ...

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds`?

Comment: @Khauri McClain But he can just call  `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds()` directly.

Comment: Yes, he can, but he want to speed it up... not to call it immediately. And also, I guess, he need to cancel "legal" call, so `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds` needs to be changed. Otherwise he'll get one "refresh" immediately + one more after legal timeout is passed.

Comment: Yes, OP can also just call it directly, but the question asked to put it on a timer. And I think this is a good answer to what seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: That could be achieved by `setTimeout(RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds, 60 * 1000);`, followed by `RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds = function () {};`.if it's not idempotent.

Comment: Thank you team for answering my question. I tried above code but it is not working. I m not good at JavaScript so could you please provide me complete code that I can enter in console.... For setTimeout(RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds, 60 * 1000);, followed by RefreshPageAfterFreePlayTimerEnds = function () {};

Answer (score -2):

If you can't access to the website code, to change the code that doesn't allow you to reduce the time coding. You can change your IP address and use the website again.

If you have to sing in to use the website, forget, else you use another account and IP you will need to wait the time restricted to use again.

Comment: I tried to change IP but it's not working. It seems that time is taken from website or linked with my account.